# How can use SSRS report inside UnitOfWork in aspnetboilerplate template?

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

Imagine there is a method in appservice which upgrade data and finally a report is made in Pdf form through Ssrs. All methods are unit of work,  so data is not committed in server until calling method uow.CompleteAsync(). therefore GenerateSampleReport() can not be called.  To solve the problem we have used [unit of work  (Isdisabled = true) so the method is written so:

```
[UnitOfWork(IsDisabled =true)]
    public async Task Method()
    {
        using (var uow = UnitOfWorkManager.Begin())
        {
            //some data manipulation

            await uow.CompleteAsync();
        }

        var pdfFile GenerateSampleReport();
    }
```

But, while providing the report, if there is any exception, report can not be generated and data manipulation must be roll backed(problem about data integrity). How to solve the problem?

Comment: What do you mean by `provide any report by data as soon as the method is not completed`?

Comment: It's not very clear what your problem is.

Comment: @aaron I edited my question. Sorry about bad English

Comment: Try calling `UnitOfWorkManager.Current.SaveChanges();` before generating a report, instead of beginning your own `UnitOfWork`.

Comment: @aaron method GenerateSampleReport() call ssrs web service that execute in different context . for example call http://localhost/ReportServer?Sampling%2FMoarefi%2F04Master&rs:Command=Render&rs:format=pdf&hcInstanceId=3

Comment: Then how do you expect it to be rolled back if it's already committed?

Comment: @aaron that is a problem. if GenerateSampleReport(); generate exception we can not roll back transaction

Comment: That's obvious. Then what?

Comment: I want to when GenerateSampleReport() throw exception,entire method roll backed

Comment: That's not possible if it's already committed. Instead, try to find out if `GenerateSampleReport` can read uncommitted.

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't begin your own Unit Of Work. And don't disable UnitOfWork. Normally if Method() is an application service method then this should work as you want.

```
 public async Task Method()
 {
       //some data manipulation... 
       var pdfFile GenerateSampleReport();//if any exception occurs in this line, the db transaction will be rolled back.
 }
```

have you checked this before?

Comment: problem is that GenerateSampleReport() call SSRS web service that placed in different context

Comment: if you can edit that web service code, return a flag that the result is success or failure. if web service has failed then throw an exception in GenerateSampleReport()